# How to make CSS checked selector work in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code, which hides menu items with class="tbuild" when the checkbox include_Ts is unchecked, works in Chrome, but not IE. Is there a straightforward way to make it work in both?

```
<style>
.tbuild {
  display: none;
}

#include_Ts:checked~select .tbuild {
  display: block;
}
</style>

<html>
<strong>Include T-builds:</strong> <input type="checkbox" id="include_Ts" />

<br><br>

<label><strong>Release #1:</strong></label>
<select id="selectedBaseRelease">
  <option value="/~releases/file2">ICC2_O-2018.06</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file2a" class="tbuild">ICC2_O-2018.06a</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file3" selected>ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file3a" class="tbuild">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6a</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file4">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP5</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file4a" class="tbuild">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP5a</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<label><strong>Release #2:</strong></label>
<select id="selectedNewRelease">
  <option value="/~releases/file1" selected>ICC2_O-2018.06-SP1</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file1a" class="tbuild">ICC2_O-2018.06-SP1a</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file2">ICC2_O-2018.06</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file2a" class="tbuild">ICC2_O-2018.06a</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file3">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6</option>
  <option value="/~releases/file3a" class="tbuild">ICC2_N-2017.09-SP6a</option></select>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: :checked has been fully supported in IE since version 9: https://caniuse.com/#search=checked

Comment: I think it is more about the form element than rules supported. this code is suppose to work in IE11 as long as select element can be restyled. here : `option {display:none;}` is not avalaible in IE11 :( ... if that is the IE you write about ....

Comment: Ugh...I am using IE 11. Is there another way to accomplish the same in that version?

Comment: You will need javascript , hidding the select and mimic it from an html structure , or use label /input inside a list. you can then make the list look like a select adding an arrow on the right